# Swift lazy static member initialization

Tags: swift

Starting from this code:

```
class Formatters {
    static let shared = Formatters()
    
    var humaneNumbers: NumberFormatter;
    
    private init() {
        humaneNumbers = NumberFormatter()
        humaneNumbers.numberStyle = .decimal
    }
}
```

(Thread safety not included here.)

I need to call this as `Formatters.shared.humaneNumbers`; I'd much rather just call `Formatters.humaneNumbers`.

Is there a way to do this with only a static property? I tried this:

```
class Formatters {
    static var humaneNumbers: NumberFormatter {
        let humaneNumbers = NumberFormatter()
        humaneNumbers.numberStyle = .decimal
        return humaneNumbers
    }
}
```

…but that becomes a static calculated property, so it's called every time instead of just once.

Then, of course, there's this approach:

```
class Formatters {
    static let humaneNumbers = NumberFormatter()
}
```

But that gives me an uncustomized NumberFormatter.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could evaluate a closure to encapsulate the configuration.

```swift
class Formatters {
    static let humaneNumbers: NumberFormatter = {
        let humaneNumbers = NumberFormatter()
        humaneNumbers.numberStyle = .decimal
        return humaneNumbers
    }()
}
```

Comment: To clarify what's going on: This is just a stored property, whose value is initialized like any other. It just happens to be the result of evaluating a closure with some other logic in it, but that's just a detail. The key detail is that OP's attempt was using a computed property, which was never holding onto the result.

Comment: Note tat this would still be possible to modify your humaneNumbers formatter's properties. `Formatters.humaneNumbers.numberStyle = .currency`

Answer (score 2):

A `Formatters` class is not a modern approach. Static computed properties are [how things are done now](https://goshdarnformatstyle.com), but they do not create `Formatter` objects.

Your `humane` style is actually the default.

```swift
extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<Double> {
  static var humane: Self { number }
  static var inhumane: Self { number.sign(strategy: .never) }
}
```

```swift
// All three are "1,234.56"
1234.56.formatted()
1234.56.formatted(.humane)
(-1234.56).formatted(.inhumane)
```

Comment: This is probably the answer to my actual problem, but not directly the answer to my question because I didn't understand static member closures. So an upvote will have to do. :)